# Second Order DE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im currently in a Calc II class at CWRU. I missed a day of class covering Second Order DE's. This topic is not covered in the textbook. Could someone direct me towards a introduction or tutorial to this topic. Here is an example of the type we are covering.
4y'+ 4y" + y = 0 ; y(0)= -12 , y'(0)= 1

Comment: For future reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Higher_Order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IntroSecondOrder.aspx) is good.

Answer (score 4):

You might also try some of 
[my notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/m215s02.html), in particular
[Second Order Linear Equations](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/lin2o/lin2o.html)
and [Constant-Coefficient Equations](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/coco/coco.html)

Answer (score 3):

MIT Open lectures would have some nice notes

Look [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/index.html) chapter 33, or [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/) Lecture 9, or do a [search](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/audio-video-courses/) on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Here is also a pretty good video lecturer's on various topics.

[PatrickJMT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soU-zRdpsoA)

and

[DrChrisTisdell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOtpqZLgxP0)

Hope this helps out.